# How to check data inside column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

i have a df and a list

```
Value   Dummy   
AB,AE     2
AE,RF,AW  2
AC,AD     2
```

I want to check list is containing the values on the column or not

```
list_of_value=['AB','AC','AD','AE']

Value     AB      AC     AD      AE  Dummy 
AB,AE     True  False  False   True    2
AE,RF,AW  False False  False   True    2 
AC,AD     False True   True    False   2
```

Tried with

```
df=(df['Value'].isin(list_of_value))
```

Not getting the desired output

Comment: `print` is a method to display stuff, you should NEVER assign the return vlaue of it

Comment: Edited with the recent one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `df['Value'].str.get_dummies`:

```
df[list_of_value] = df['Value'].str.get_dummies(sep=',')[list_of_value].astype(bool)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
      Value  Dummy     AB     AC     AD     AE
0     AB,AE      2   True  False  False   True
1  AE,RF,AW      2  False  False  False   True
2     AC,AD      2  False   True   True  False
```